# Javascript prototype and __proto__ and getPrototypeOf issue

Tags: javascript, prototype-programming

I have a simple class in javascript:

```
function foo() {
    this.bar = "bar";
}

var test = new foo;

console.log(foo.prototype,foo.__proto__)
/*output: foo {
               constructor: function foo() { 
               __proto__:   Object
              }
          ,
          function Empty() {}
*/
console.log(test,test.prototype,test.__proto__,test.__proto__.__proto__)
/*output: foo {
              bar: "bar"
              __proto__: foo
          }
          ,
          undefined
          ,
          foo {
              constructor: function foo() {
              __proto__: Object
          }
          ,
          Object {
              ...
          }
      */
```

What i dont understand:

At the first log the `foo.prototype` had the `__proto__` attribute which was an `Object`
At the second log the `test.__proto__` had the `__proto__` attribute which was an `Object`

When to use `__proto__` and when `prototype`, what is the difference?

---

**UPDATE:**

In **[John Resig's blog](http://ejohn.org/blog/objectgetprototypeof/)** in the **instanceOf** section there is something waht I don't understand:

If i use `var asd = "asd";`[`Object.getPrototypeOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/GetPrototypeOf)`(asd)` it throws a `TypeError` but
If i use `var dsa = new String("dsa");`[`Object.getPrototypeOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/GetPrototypeOf)`(dsa)` it returns `String`
**But** `asd.constructor.prototype == dsa.constructor.prototype` is **`true`**

Why is the [`Object.getPrototypeOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/GetPrototypeOf)`(asd)` throws error? This is a string, isn't it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Always use `prototype` or [`Object.getPrototypeOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/GetPrototypeOf).

`__proto__` is non-standard and has been deprecated by [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto).

John Resig has a good [blog entry](http://ejohn.org/blog/objectgetprototypeof/) about it.

---

The reason why `test.prototype` is undefined is because you created a new object that does not have a constructor prototype. Here's an example of when to use `Object.getPrototypeOf`.

```
js> function foo(){}
js> typeof foo.prototype;
object
js> var f = new foo();
js> typeof f.prototype;
undefined
js> typeof Object.isPrototypeOf(f);
object
js> typeof f.constructor.prototype;
object
js> foo.prototype === Object.getPrototypeOf(f);
true
js> foo.prototype === f.constructor.prototype;
true
```

---

As you can tell, inheritance in JavaScript is tricky. Lets look at an example:

```
js> typeof "asdf";
string
js> typeof String("asdf");
string
```

The string literal is of type string. The same is true when calling `String()` as a function. Now, because of behavior of the `new` operator, a new object is created, with the prototype of `String()` as its parent.

```
js> var s = new String("asdf");
js> typeof s;
object
```

Because JS likes to coerce things, you can get at the string literal a few ways:

```
js> s
asdf
js> s.valueOf();
asdf
js> typeof s
object
js> typeof s.valueOf();
string
```

[Prototypal Inheritance in JavaScript](http://javascript.crockford.com/prototypal.html) by Crockford helped me a lot when learning about JS inheritance.

From Mozilla's [Strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) page:

> String objects may be created by
>   calling the constructor new String().
>   The String object wraps JavaScript's
>   string primitive data type with the
>   methods described below. The global
>   function String() can also be called
>   without new in front to create a
>   primitive string. String literals in
>   JavaScript are primitive strings.

Comment: but as you see the second log, `test.prototype ==undefined`

Comment: I amended my answer with example repl output.

Comment: thanks for this really nice example. now i understand everything.

Comment: I updated my question. There is something what i dont understand in John's blog

Comment: Where you have Object.isPrototypeOf(f), I think you want Object.getPrototypeOf

Answer (score 5):

`__proto__` is an intermediary object between an object and it's prototype. The biggest benefit in using it is that you can change the prototype chain for an object entirely without modifying the instance or the prototype.

Example:

```
function F() {} 
F.prototype.a = 1;
var f = new F();
f.__proto__ = { b : 2 }; 
"a" in f => false; 
"b" in f => true;
```

But as Jeremy said, `__proto__` is deprecated. The only use case would be if you would like to add a set of properties to an object, changing its prototype without having to iterate through each one. Not a big deal.