# Why do these two references to a prototype return different values

Tags: javascript, prototype

```
var fn = function(){};

console.log(fn.prototype == Object.getPrototypeOf(fn));  //false
```

Huh?

Comment: Have a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6113118/571194 - not an identical question, but it does answer it

Comment: The prototype property of a function is nothing but a blueprint. It is the object that will be assigned as prototype to objects, created via `new fn()` but it is not the actual prototype of the function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Object.getPrototypeOf(fn)` will return `function(){}` because that's the prototype of all functions .

while `.prototype` property represents the methods and properties of new objects  when `fn`  is used to construct (invoked with `new`).

```js
var fn = function (){};

console.log(fn.prototype); // fn {}

console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(fn)); // function() {}
/*this is like */
console.log(fn.constructor.prototype) // since the constructor is a function...


var child = new fn() 

console.log(Object.getPrototypeOf(child)); // fn {}
```